# What is rewriting my user related URLs?

Tags: 6, uri, users

My main username is 'bw_admin'. If I visit my login page at `localhost:8888/mysite/?q=user` I would be able to login but after my login I can't view the account page. Instead I get a HTTP500 internal server error. What I notice it that the underscore of my username is being deleted automatically so I would be getting `localhost:8888/mysite/?q=user/bwadmin` instead of `localhost:8888/mysite/?q=user/bw_admin`.

after getting the error if I would just edit the bad URL into the URL of the mainpage of the site I can go on while logged in as admin. But it's important for future user to not have this problem so they won't panic

Here's a list of the modules that I've installed in case this might be a typical problem related to a certain module.

addthis
addtoany
admin_menu
advanced_help
auto_nodetitle
autoload
cck
content_profile
context
ctools
devel
devel_themer
fckeditor
filefield
google_analytics
image
imageapi
imagecache
imagefield
imce
imce_wysiwyg
insert
jquery_ui
jquery_ui_dialog
jquery_update
lightbox2
menu_breadcrumb
module_filter
nice_menus
oauth
panels
pathauto
token
twitter
views
webform
wysiwyg
wysiwyg_imageupload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module that creates a URL like localhost:8888/mysite/?q=user/bwadmin (or localhost:8888/mysite/user/bwadmin, with clean URLs enabled) is the Pathauto module, which creates path alias for user, node, and taxonomy term URLs.

Check the module settings; there is a set of options that allows replacing some specific characters that would cause some problems; one of those characters is the underscore. In your case, the module is set to strip off underscores from the path alias it generates.

Comment: I was pretty sure it wasn't any stringfunction from pathauto but I checked again after you mentioned it. I never ever touched the pathauto preferences and until short the underscore remained in my URL just fine. It seemed to happened 'out of the blue' even though nothing really does. The disappearing of my underscore is actually just 1 manifestation of HTTP 500 error messages that come with user related URLs. Another manifestation is a http500 error showing when trying to click on 'my account'. This seems to be entirely impossible.